# Cache hits (ehCache)

Tags: oracle, ehcache

Is there any way or any parameter that can be used to find the number of hits to cache. We are using Ehcache for our application. Appreciate any help on this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at Cache.getStatistics()?

http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#getStatistics()
http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Statistics.html

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("someCache");
Statistics stats = cache.getStatistics();

long hits  = stats.getInMemoryHits();
long misses = stats.getInMemoryMisses();
```